# How to examine and edit each line in python?

Tags: python, csv, split, line, edit

I have only had a week's experience with python, so please forgive my ignorance.

I have a specific column called 'a' from a CSV file. By printing a, Python prints out all the rows of the column in new lines, which is the format I want it in. How would I identify the 3rd last character of each line, and perform an if function in python.

```
if line[-3] == list(string.ascii_letters):
      Add "registry"

# To focus on third last character and determine if it is an alphabet
# Could you please explain how to add a string to the end of the line, 
# and remove a certain number of characters

elif line[-3] == ":":
      Remove the last 5 characters and Add "rex"
elif line[-3] == "0"
      Remove the last 3 characters and Add "tx"
```

Would `a.readlines()` work for this purpose?

I have also tried to implement rstrip with very little success:

```
for line in a:
    line = line.rstrip()
    process(line)
```

Should I use `a = a.replace("str1", "str2")` here?

**Example**
I am unable to post any images. However a table of the following format:

```
Mat    Debt   Severe    Weather    Dot
sdfs    sdfg    ghgd    sadg:jj  sjdkfsadf
fsdafs  dfg    fgdsf    tdkkkk   sdfsdaf
sadf    hgdf    adfsg   dfgjjj0as   dfbs
```

a is defined as a row [n] using 'rows = csv.reader(f)'
If n is 3, the output is as follows:

```
sadg:jj
tdkkkk
dfgjjj0as
```

I want the ouput to be:

```
sarex
tdkkkregistry
dfgjjjtx
```

Comment: Could you add an example of what the input would look like, and what the output should look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
    with open('csvfile','r') as a,open('csvout','w') as out_csv:
        for line in a.readlines():
            if line[-3].isalpha():
                  line += 'registry'
            elif line[-3] == ":":
                  line = line[:-3] + 'rex'
            elif line[-3] == "0"
                  line = line[:-3] + 'tx'
            out_csv.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: You can get rid of the call to `list` in `if line[-3] in list(string.ascii_letters)`.

Comment: More: `line[-3] in string.ascii_letters` is more usually written `line[-3].isalpha()`.

Comment: Does this remove the last couple of characters, and then add the strings?

Comment: @anatu line[:-3] is line minus the last 3 characters

Comment: Okay thanks very much. However I have not defined line anywhere. Is there any way to define it in terms of a?

Answer (score 0):

When checking if the string is an ascii character you were checking if it was a list which contained all ascii characters. You would want to see if it is in the list by using 'in' instead of '=='

```
if line[-3] in string.ascii_letters:
      line += "registry"
elif line[-3] == ":":
      line = line[:-5]
      line += "rex"
elif line[-3] == "0"
      line = line[:-3]
      line += "tx"
```

Now for looping trough each line, there is quite a few ways of doing this. Here's two ways of doing so.

First is using the splitlines() method. This will create a list containing a string for each line. Then loop trough it.

```
for line in a.splitlines():
          ...
```

Second way is using split and splitting the \n characters.

```
for line in a.split("\n"):
          ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are trying to create an updated CSV file or if you just need to display the updated values?

The following script does both:

```
import csv, re

with open("input.csv", "r") as f_input, open("output.csv", "wb") as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input))

    for cols in csv_input:
        if cols[3][-3].isalpha():
            cols[3] += 'registry'
        elif cols[3][-3] == ":":
            cols[3] = cols[3][:-5] + 'rex'
        elif cols[3][-3] == "0":
            cols[3] = cols[3][:-3] + 'tx'

        csv_output.writerow(cols)
        print cols[3]
```

This will print the following output:

```
sarex
tdkkkkregistry
dfgjjjtx
```

And will create an output CSV file as follows:

```
Mat,Debt,Severe,Weather,Dot
sdfs,sdfg,ghgd,sarex,sjdkfsadf
fsdafs,dfg,fgdsf,tdkkkkregistry,sdfsdaf
sadf,hgdf,adfsg,dfgjjjtx,dfbs
```

Tested using Python 2.7